# bind dateformat string to value in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have this in my web.config

```
<add key="DateFormat" value="dd/MM/yy"/>
```

And I want to use the ajax calendar extended with the format property and bind it to this format.

But I havent found the expression in how to do it.

Comment: Put you ajax calendar in a user control, and bind the format on the pageload event of the user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `<%$ AppSettings: DateFormat %>` (per the [ASP.NET Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) on MSDN)